# Non-public top level class in Java

Tags: java

What's the reason of making top-level class non-public in Java?

Let's say we have `Foo.java`, there could be

```
class Foo {
}
```

or

```
public class Foo {
}
```

I understand that there will be some class - visibility issues with the former example (probably it won't be visible from other packages). But anyway, are there any reasons why someone may want to do as in the first code sample?

UPD: What cons I see in the former solution: nobody cares that it's `non-public`. That class can be simply extended by some other `public` class in the same package later, then, non-public part of the class may bring you visibility/access issues.

Comment: cause if it is not necessary, why need to put extra code on it~

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example.
No one needs to know about existence of our ConcreteDocument.

### `DocumentIF.java`

```
public interface DocumentIF {
}
```

### `ConcreteDocument.java`

```
class ConcreteDocument implements DocumentIF {
}
```

### `DocumentFactory.java`

```
public class DocumentFactory {
    public DocumentIF createDocument() {
        return new ConcreteDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that these classes are in different files ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Typically, you make a class package-private because you don't want the class to be used outside the package. When a top-level class isn't public, it's private to the package.

Say you have a package with a number of classes that must communicate the same sort of data with one another. But this data structure is an implementation detail and so you don't want it being used by user code. Making the transfer class package private maintains this sort of package level encapsulation.

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that there will be some class - visibility issues with the former example (probably it won't be visible from other packages).

That seems to me to be reason enough to use it if you want to keep the class private to that one package.

---

Just noticed another use! It seems you can only have one public top-level class per code file, but any number of non-public top-level classes. Haven't verified it personally, but if true that could be quite useful to prevent cluttering your project folder and to group classes with related functionality that aren't needed outside of the package.

Comment: The second point is true, but it is a bad practice to put more than one top-level class in a file.  Imagine you decided that Alpha.java should have a public Alpha class and a non-public Helper class.  Then your colleage (working in the same package) decided that Beta.java should have a public Beta class and a non-public Helper class.  Collision!  This collision would have been averted if (1) you both nested the Helper class inside their respective top-level classes (best); or (2) you both put the Helper class in its own compilation unit (the second developer would see the problem right away).

Comment: @emory: That's why I tend to prefer the way Python and similar languages handle things, where each file is itself a module with its own module-level namespace, and collisions like that don't occur normally. Effectively like your nesting solution. ...In fact, I guess you could emulate that functionality by just using the one top-level class as a wrapper for the classes you want to consolidate without having any actual functionality itself, though I suppose that's kind of going against good programming practice in Java as well.

Comment: @emory if that's the worst problem then I don't think it is much of an issue. Developer will get notified the first time they compile and it will be an easy fix. Surely even the IDE will notify them before that.

Answer (score 2):

Classes without a `public` or `protected` modifier are only visible inside the package they reside. If you think of *components* and *interfaces* there is a reason for leaving out the `public` modifier. Let's say you have a `public` class `MyCompontent` that internally uses other classes, but does not want to publish those to the outside world (users of the component) it makes sense to leave out the visibility modifier.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered good design to keep the visibility of a class to the most minimum required. The reasons that I can think of:

1. The class can easily change in the future without causing breakages in external packages as the external packages do not have access to the class. In this regard it might be even better to start off a class by making it a private inner class.
2. The class being package visible cannot be extended by classes in external packages. This again makes it easier for this class to change without causing breaking changes in external packages. If this class was not meant to be extended then it would be even better to make this final.
3. A public visible class becomes a part of the exported API of your library. If you are a library designer, it is better to keep your exported API as small as possible because you do not want to confuse your consumer with un-necessary classes/details. Item 1 would again hold good in this case.

The book "Effective Java" by Josh Bloch is an excellent reference for Idiomatic Java code and design.