# Why cannot I use a package-private (implicit) class as the top-level class of a java file?

Tags: java, class, private, access-modifiers

I am new to Java. Maybe the question is a bit naive.

For example, I have a pkg1, in which there are 2 Java files: f1.java and f2.java

As the title, I feel it is reasonable
to use a package-private-top-level class for f1, 
then use a public-top-level class for f2, 
then the outside of pkg1 can still access f1 via f2.

I can even have f3, f4... ..., which are all using package-private class as their top-level class. Then f2.java will become a package-interface file for the rest of files in pkg1.

So, why is the fact that a top-level class must be public? Just to prevent from unnecessary complexity?

Comment: "So, why is the fact that a top-level class must be public?" It doesn't have to be. Please show some code instead of describing it, and tell us what error you're getting...

Comment: Thx all, I just asked the question before trying, because I saw many questions said "a java file must contain only one public class with the same name as the file". I took it for granted.

Comment: It means it can only contain *at most* one public class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), **public** isn't the only possible modifier for top-level class:

> A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package

So, basically, there's no problem in making some classes protected or package-private if your design requests it.

Term 'top-level class' actually exists in Java as well as terms 'inner class' and 'nested class', I suggest you to take a look on [this page](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top) to clear some basics of java class hierarchy.

Comment: Spot on! This is exactly what I want.

Comment: glad it helps :) In case you have no more questions here, I'd appreciate if you mark this answer as accepted, otherwise feel free to ask

Comment: Sure, I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996739/non-public-top-level-class-in-java, which may helps

Answer (score 3):

> why is the fact that a top-level class must be public?

A "top level" class in Java is just a class that isn't a nested class (a class inside another class — [JLS§8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html)). They are not required to be `public`.

You may be thinking of applications that are run via the `java` tool (not all are!). The class meant to be used as the entry point for the `java` tool is usually shown as `public` in examples, but it *isn't* required to be. It *is* required to have a public static void `main` method accepting a `String` array, but the class itself doesn't have to be `public`.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A top level class should be public because a public class can be used any where in the java universe,but if you declare a class private or protected then its sole purpose is lost declaring a class private will not allow this class to be visible to any other class and marking it is protected will also do the same thing.Its always recommended to make a class default or public.